# Auto Reply with notes, email body and add CC

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am try to CC second person but I am getting Error run-time 13 **`Type mismatch`**.

```
Option Explicit
'// Auto Replay with notes and email body- run Action Script
Public Sub ReplywithNote(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim olDocument As Word.Document
    Dim olSelection As Word.Selection
    Dim olReply As MailItem
    Dim olRecipient As Outlook.Recipient


    Set olReply = Item.ReplyAll
    olReply.Display

    Set olRecipient = myItem.Recipient.Add("omar")
        olRecipient.Type = olCC

    Set olInspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set olDocument = olInspector.WordEditor
    Set olSelection = olDocument.Application.Selection

    olSelection.InsertBefore "Received, Thank you."

    '// Uncomment to send
    olReply.Send

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Recipient not Recipients

```
 Dim olRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
```

Comment: From your comment then the question has been answered. This should address the unasked question.   Set olRecipient = olReply.Recipients.Add("omar@test.com").  olReply not myItem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.recipients.add.aspx) method of the Recipients class creates a new recipient in the Recipients collection. The parameter is the name of the recipient; it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP e-mail address of the recipient.

If you run the following sample code in Outlook there is no need to create a new Application instance, use the Application property available in VBA out of the box.

```
 Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") // Application
 Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Jon Grande")
 myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

Don't forget to call the Resolve method of the Recipient class after adding a new one. Or just the ResolveAll method of the Recipients class to resolve recipients against the address book.

See [How to: Specify Different Recipient Types for a Mail Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184598.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I am getting Error run-time 13 Type mismatch `Set olRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("omar@test.com")` i have updated my question. any advice :-)

Comment: As I wrote, you should use the Application property to get a running Outlook Application instance instead of creating a new one.